# How to send Image of type file(From flutter mobile application ) to php database

Tags: php, database, flutter, dart, server

This is how I picked a file from device

```
  onPressed: () async {
                                    FilePickerResult? result =
                                        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                                      type: FileType.custom,
                                      allowedExtensions: [
                                        'jpg',
                                        'pdf',
                                        'doc'
                                      ],
                                    );
                                    List<File> files = result!.paths
                                        .map((path) => File(path!))
                                        .toList();
                                    context
                                        .read<Dropper>()
                                        .fileCheck(result: result);

                                    myfile = files[0];
                                  },
```

Then I Converted to Uint8List :

```
  Uint8List imgbytes = await myFile.readAsBytes();
```

Now I am sending that file to Php database

```
 final url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/addSurvey";
  final uri = Uri.parse(url);

  final response = await api.post(uri, headers: {
    'Authorization': token,
  }, body: {
    "bill_image": imgbytes
```

}

It throws error msg like this :  `type 'Uint8List' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

Answer (score 0):

```
  var url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/addSurvey";
                        Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
 'Authorization': token,};
                        var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url));
                        if(_image != null){
                          var pic = await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('bill_image', imgbytes , filename: 'photo.jpg');
                          request.files.add(pic);
                        }
    request.send().then((result) async {
                          http.Response.fromStream(result).then((response) async {
                            if (response.statusCode == 200)
                            {
                              
                            }
                            else{
                              
                            }

                            return response.body;

                          });
                        }).catchError((err) => print('merror : '+err.toString())).whenComplete(()
                        {

                        });
```

Try it using multipart request.

Answer (score 0):

if php is accepting parameter as file type File then you need to send image as multipart request i guess.

```
    var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'token'
};
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/addSurvey'));
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('bill_image', 'path to your file'));
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```